# В поиск не попадают значения, при соблюдении условий. Выведите список клиентов у которых ВСЕ тикеты закрыты (status = 0)

Tags: sql, postgresql

ticket_id   custumer_id status  open    close
1   1   1   01.01.2015
2   1   0   01.01.2015  10.01.2015
4   1   0   02.01.2015  10.01.2015
11  1   1   09.01.2015
12  1   0   10.01.2015  18.01.2015
14  1   1   12.01.2015
5   2   0   03.01.2015  11.01.2015
6   2   0   04.01.2015  12.01.2015
7   2   0   05.01.2015
15  2   0   13.01.2015  16.01.2015
16  2   0   14.01.2015  17.01.2015
8   3   1   06.01.2015
9   3   0   07.01.2015  12.01.2015
10  3   0   08.01.2015  16.01.2015
3   4   1   01.01.2015
13  4   0   11.01.2015  18.01.2015
18  5   1   16.01.2015
17  6   0   15.01.2015  18.01.2015

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть база данных.
Задание:
**Выведите список клиентов у которых ВСЕ тикеты закрыты (status = 0)**

Проблема:
я не в совершенстве знаю SQL, мой запрос с
select distinct customer_id
from ticket
where status=0 and close_dt is not null
не подходит
правильный ответ customer_id=6.
Как мне написать запрос, что если например у customer_id=1 есть незакрытый тикет, то как его убрать из базы данных поиски и он не попадал в выборку, где у него есть закрытые тикеты.

Comment: select customer_id
from ticket
where close_dt is not null 
except      
select customer_id
from ticket
where close_dt is null

Comment: `SELECT custumer_id FROM ticket GROUP BY 1 HAVING NOT MAX(status);`